# __newindex api C lua

Tags: lua

The question is how to do the following, from the Lua C API:

```
settings.default.color = 10 --(raise an error)
persistent.channel.xxx = 15 --(call function to set)
y = persistent.channel.xxx --(call function to read)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a proxy table. See http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html